# Why is it allocating memory like this in C?

Tags: c

Currently learning C and learning about linked lists.

While looking through the examples I see this bit of code:

```
struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

My question is why is `malloc` being multiplied with a Node pointer? From my understanding to allocate memory you just need to use `malloc` and give it the parameter of a Node.

Also why is the parameter inside `malloc` just a `struct Node` instead of being a `struct Node*` when the variable is a pointer?

Comment: Side note: In contrast to C++, in C, casting the result of `malloc` is not necessary. You may want to read this for further information: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/12149471)

Comment: Using a cast (although strictly unnecessary and preferably avoided), is often done for compatibility with C++ (especially with header files that define inlined or static functions).

Comment: `malloc` isn't being multiplied with anything. In this context, the `*` means "pointer". That is, it's casting the return value from `malloc` from a void pointer (a `void*` type) to a `struct Node` pointer (a `struct Node*` type). Also note that casting the return value of `malloc` and friends is [generally discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: as for your 2nd question, you want to allocate memory for the _thing being pointed to_, which is "one level up" from the pointer. You have a `struct Node*`. This must point to a `struct Node`, so you allocate enough space for one (or more) `struct Node`(s). The preferred way is `struct Node* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));`. WIth that, the type of `node` can change to anything (eg, `struct Node2* node`) and the argument to `malloc` doesn't need any updating, since `*node` transforms into the correct type "automatically".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Andreasdet: Even if your proposed dupicate question is probably useful for OP, it  does not answer OP's main question.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Would a question about C syntax be a potentially better duplicate target?

Comment: @Andreasdet: I don't think that it is appropriate to close this question at all (also not as a duplicate), unless you find a question that is very similar to this one (which is probably unlikely).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation of [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), that function requires one parameter which specifies the number of bytes to allocate.

Therefore, in order to allocate sufficient memory to represent a single node, you must pass the size of an object of type `struct Node` to the function `malloc`.

Although it may be possible for you to calculate this size manually, the easiest way to determine the size of an object of type `struct Node` is to use the [sizeof operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof). That is why the expression `sizeof(struct Node)` is being passed as a parameter to the function `malloc`.

Using the expression `sizeof(struct Node*)` instead of `sizeof(struct Node)` as a parameter for `malloc` would be wrong, as that would only allocate sufficient memory for a pointer, but you want to allocate sufficient memory for an object of type `struct Node` (which is probably larger than a pointer).

In the line

```
struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

the `(struct Node*)` is a [type cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). It converts the data type `void *` returned by `malloc` to a `struct Node *`.

In this context, the `*` means "pointer", not multiplication. If you are unfamiliar with the concept of pointers, then I suggest that you first learn the basics of the programming language C, before you attempt to understand this. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/12149471) is a list of books. I suggest that you buy one under the category "Beginner".

Note that in contrast to C++, in C, casting the result of `malloc` is not necessary and generally discouraged. See the following question for further information:

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/12149471)